# Show that for real $u,x,y,z>0$, $f(u,x,y,z)=\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{2z^4}{y^6}+3u^3z^2+\frac{5x^2y^4z^2}{u}$ has no minimum

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization, convex-optimization

Question: Show that for real $u,x,y,z>0$, 
$$f(u,x,y,z)=\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{2z^4}{y^6}+3u^3z^2+\frac{5x^2y^4z^2}{u}$$ has no minimum.

I found the Hessian matrix of $f$ is very complicated, it's hard to show the semi-positive definite property.

My guess is to use some inequality to obtain a constant lower bound of $f$, then verify that the equation can not be reached.

However I cannot find the proper inequality to use.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Hi, but we cannot set $z=0$, since $u,x,y,z$ should be positive, as the question stated.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN sorry I deleted your comment by mistake...

Comment: I'm curious why you tagged this as convex optimization. It is almost certainly not convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that the quantity must be positive, because each individual term in the sum is strictly positive.

Now consider $$f(1,q^{-1/3},q^{1/6},q^{1/2})=q+2q+3q+5q=11q$$ You can obtain any positive value $\epsilon>0$ simply by choosing $$q=\epsilon/11, \quad u=1, \quad x=q^{-1/3}, \quad y=q^{1/6}, \quad z=q^{1/2}.$$
Thus $f$ can be *arbitrarily close* to zero, but not zero itself, because $q\rightarrow 0$ means that $x\rightarrow +\infty$ and $y,z\rightarrow 0$. So we have $\inf_{u,x,y,z} f(u,x,y,z) =0$, but there is no tuple $(u,x,y,z)$ that attains this infimum.